# Variable passing is not overriden with jQuery

Tags: jquery, overriding

So basically, I want to override the current `maxFileSize` with the `var allowablefile`. However, the correct allowablefile value is sent in the console, but when the value is overridden, the value is still at 500 which is what I declared it at first. What am I doing wrong? Here is the whole script.

```
<script>    
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var allowablefile = "500";
            $.get( "size.php", function( datas ) {
                var currfile = datas;
                var rtplan = '<?php echo $rtplan; ?>';
                if (rtplan == "standard") {
                    var maxfile = "40000000";
                    allowablefile = maxfile - currfile;
                } 
                else if (rtplan == "pro") {
                    var maxfile = "110000000";
                    allowablefile = maxfile - currfile;
                }
                else if (rtplan == "turbo") {
                    var maxfile = "60000000";
                    allowablefile = maxfile - currfile;
                }
                console.log(allowablefile);
            });
            var allw = allowablefile.toString();
            var settings = {
                url: "../upload.php",
                method: "POST",
                fileName: "myfile",
                multiple: true,
                maxFileSize: allw,
                uploadButtonClass:"btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right",
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                {
                    $("#status").html('<span class="label label-success">File uploaded</span>').fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#status").fadeOut(7000);

                },
                onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                {       
                    $("#status").html('<span class="label label-danger">File upload failed</span>').fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#status").fadeOut(7000);
                }
            }


            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
        });
 </script>
```

I tried declaring the value in a `name` value of a div, but that still did not work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that ajax calls are asynchronous. Thus the lines after `$.get()` will be executed **before** the lines in the ajax success callback.

On way to approach this is to place all the code after `$.get()` inside the `$.get()` success callback.